# Blender not rendering as expected and transparent background gone

Tags: lighting

I was following along a tutorial to make braided tubes, which created the desired effect, but when I went to render, the entire scene is greyed out. WTF

[image: greyed out render]

The following is a screenshot of the scene - very simple, one camera and one light. The point light is set to 1000 W

[image]

BTW, in the previous version, that is used 2.93, I had my background set to transparent. How did that change in the upgrade to 3.2?

Comment: Sorry if I do not reply quickly, I have to leave for the evening shift

Comment: Transparent backghround in 3.2 is under _Render Properties > Film > Transparent (checkbox)_.

Comment: Thank you @https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/75504/christopher-bennett